# In which way can I make an Auto-React feature for a discord bot that I'm writing in the discord.py API?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Basically, I'd like my discord bot to react with an emote to messages that have keywords in them. I tried tutorials, using if-statements, and both of those didn't work.

````
   async def on_message(message):
      if "react to me" in message.content.lower():
        await client.react(message)```
````

Comment: Here are the docs for adding [reactions](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?#discord.Message.add_reaction) to a message. Try to follow the docs, recently updated tutorials, you seem to be referring to an outdated one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple function, if you want it to use a random emoji from the server, you would have to get the emoji id, but you can do this.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    emoji = client.get_emoji(#insert custom emoji id)
    if re.match("react to me", message.content.lower):
        await message.add_reaction(emoji)
    await client.process_commands(message)
```

This will match any message that only says "react to me"

EDIT:

This method can not use default emojis (thumbs up for example), it uses customs emojis in the server, you can use `\:put the name of the emoji in between these signs:` to get something like this `<:name:id>`

Example:
[image]

so the id for the emoji (what you will be putting inside the `add_reaction()` is the `672251623422296117` only.

If you want to use universal emojis (default), you have to find the unicode of it and put it in as a string (inside "").
Example: the unicode for  is `\U0001F3D3`, so you will put that inside the function.

Here is where you can find the unicode for the default emojis: https://emojipedia.org/unicode-9.0/

It will look like this [image]

Which means that the unicode for that emoji is `\U0001F923` (replace `U+` with `\U000`, making it `U+1F923` = `\U0001F923`)

add `await client.process_commands(message)` at the end of the function to allow other functions to work

Comment: i get an error saying 

```File "C:\Users\anyuser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\re.py", line 173, in match
    return _compile(pattern, flags).match(string)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object```

Comment: Is because it didn't find the emoji id, change the id to an emoji that exists in the server. It is my mistake, I should have known, but default emojis do not have IDs

Comment: I still get the same error for some reason. Here's the code:
```@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    emoji = client.get_emoji("<:redheart:815750746619379754>")
    if re.match("react to me", message.content.lower):
        await message.add_reaction(emoji)```

Comment: You are only suppose to use the numbers of the emoji id, also I edited the answer to explain you how to use it with default emojis.

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm annoying you, but I still get the same error. Here's the code https://pastebin.com/5D3Drwv2

Comment: is because you are using `message.content.lower`, `.lower` won't work

Comment: if you really want to use `.lower`, then it has to be `message.content.lower()`

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: if you could you mark this answer as accepted, thank you

Comment: what other commands are you trying to do?

Comment: I see what you mean, I edited the answer for you